# How to do elif in a while loop

Tags: python

I'm doing Al Sweigarts How to Automate the Boring Stuff, so I'm fairly new at Python. I'm trying to do a simple elif in a while loop but i get a syntax error:

```
import sys

while True:
    print("Type to exit")
    response = input()
    if response == "Exit":
        sys.exit()
    print("You typed " + response)

    elif response == "exit":
        sys.exit()
        print("You typed " + response)
```

Comment: Your `print` needs to be indented to where the call to `exit` is. It being unindented like that is ending the `if`.

Comment: How do you intend for your program to print anything after exiting? I think there is a deeper problem with your design than just the indentation here. I suggest drawing a flow-chart for what you want your program to do; it might help you get the code logically correct.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I learned that I am not supposed to print after exiting the program. I didn't really think about that since that what he does in the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to print anything after exiting the program, so I modified it. I convert the response to upper letters, so you don't need to try all conbinations

```
import sys

while True:
    print("Type to exit")
    response = input()
    print("You typed " + response)
    if response.upper() == "EXIT":
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

The first

```py
     print("You typed " + response)
```

is on the same indentation level than your `if`, so when your `elif` comes, there is no `if` to work with. The `print(...)` statement terminated it.

---

Here is your code with correct indentation, and the `print(...)` statement before the `sys.exit()` call, otherwise nothing will be printed (thanks kaya for pointing it out) :

```py
import sys

while True:
    print("Type to exit")
    response = input()
    if response == "Exit":
        print("You typed " + response)
        sys.exit()

    elif response == "exit":
        print("You typed " + response)
        sys.exit()
```

---

I suggest you to improve your `if` condition to make it simpler without altering the case of the input :

```py
import sys

while True:
    print("Type to exit")
    response = input()
    if response == "Exit" or response == "exit":
        print("You typed " + response)
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: This fixes the problem, but the code still doesn't really make sense; you can't `print` after the program has exited.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

while True:
    print("Type to exit")
    response = input()
    if response == "Exit":
        print("Exit1 " + response)
        sys.exit()


    elif response == "exit":
        print("Exit2 " + response)
        sys.exit()
```

Also you can use:

```
import sys

while True:
    print("Type to exit")
    response = input()
    response = response.lower()
    if response == "exit":
        print("Exit program with title '" + response+"'")
        sys.exit()
```